# Does removing the javascript characters(' " \ &) from input script prevents XSS?

Tags: javascript, html, xss

I have following  html input string

```
<p><script>alert("hi")</script></p>
<img src=x:alert('xss') height= "20" width ="40" onerror=eval(src) alt="xssdemo"</img>
```

Instead of escaping the characters(' " & ) using backslash('\'), removing these characters completely will prevent XSS popups ?

Basically here I don't want to use traditional \ escaping, since it will break  the html format. I am thinking to remove the charactes itself completely.
eg: height = \"20\".

Comment: No. You’re missing several options of constructing strings.

Comment: @Xufox: I didn't understand your point, Do you mean, I can't create the string with above 4  characters? can you explain me with an example

Comment: You _can_ create strings without the above four characters. That’s my point. See [template literals](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Template_literals).

Comment: See the [XSS Filter Evasion Cheat Sheet](https://www.owasp.org/index.php/XSS_Filter_Evasion_Cheat_Sheet).

Answer (score 1):

No. Counter-example:

```
<img src=nothing onerror=document.title++>
```

In fact you may as well execute some arbitrary code that way, provided you convert it to [JSFuck](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/JSFuck) beforehand.